# FileMaker loop the best way?

Tags: filemaker

I have a Projects table and within Projects you have to choose a ProjectType.
Some ProjectType are pre populated with ChargeoutHours.

When I create a Project I want to be able to select a ProjectType from the ProjectType table.  However I then want the ability to be able to change the Chargeout hours without changing the original ProjectType setup.

Is the only way to do this is to create a new Project type table and use a loop to copy the ProjectType and ChargeoutHours to this new table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a Project I want to be able to select a ProjectType from the ProjectType table. However I then want the ability to be able to change the Chargeout hours without changing the original ProjectType setup.

Assuming that `ChargeoutHours` is eventually an attribute of a Project, you should **[lookup](http://www.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Flookups.html)** the default value from the selected `ProjectType` into a field in the `Projects` table. Then you can adjust the value for the individual project without changing the default value for the type and vice versa.

There is no need to create another table or to loop anything; all you need is a relationship between the two tables you already have (assuming you already have the two tables, `Projects` and `ProjectTypes`; your question is not entirely clear on this point).

Comment: ProjectTypes is a Many to Many relationship with ChargeoutRates.  The ProjectTypes is a set list done say in the management side of the system. A ProjectType can either have no Relationship to ChargeoutRates or have lots.  A user will create a Project and then select a ProjectTypes to relate to that Project. I want the use to be able to choose a ProjectTypes but also be able to edit it without changing the list. I understand if it was just one field I could do a lookup, however this could be lots of fields from both ProjectTypes and ChargeoutRates. Thanks for you advice

Comment: According to your description, each project has only one type. Therefore the relationship between Projects and ProjectTypes.is one-to-many and there is no room for a join table between the two. You did not mention a ChargeoutRates table in your question and I don't understand its role here.

Comment: A ProjectTypes has a join table with ChargeoutRates. This allows us to set the ProjectType with the different ChargeoutRates it takes to complete a Project.  The user when creating a Project chooses a ProjectType this will then pull through the chargeourRates associated with that ProjectType to build the Project. However we want to be able the change the chargeoutrates with out changing the original list.

Comment: I am afraid I don't fully follow your description. Do you want each project to have **multiple** charge rates, that can be modified independently? If so, you will need to use another table for this and import the default rates into it.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. Would the best way to do this be setting the ProjectType in Projects and then loop through the chargeoutrates to a new table? Or is there another way to import them into a new table?

Comment: You could loop or you could import them - with only a handful of records (I presume) it makes little difference. -- To import: (a) set a variable to ProjectID; (b) GTRR to find the related rates; (c) import them into the ProjectRates table; and (d) populate the ProjectID field in the imported set using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely have a join table between these two tables to allow for such adjustments and to possibly also contain other data belonging to the ProjectType choice.

Depending on how this is organized, lookups or auto enter calcs are the usual practices.